# Cannot do "ls" in FTP while port forwarding to SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, port-forwarding

When I log in to SSH while forwarding my local port, it's 21 FTP port, with the command:

> ssh -R 2101:localhost:21 root@192.168.100.5 -p 8288

After successfully logging in, I sent this command in the SSH:

> ftp ikiw@localhost -p 2101

The command runs normally, and I also successfully logged into FTP smoothly, but when in FTP, I want to see a list of files available with the command `ls` or `dir` and I get this error:

> ftp: Can't connect to '::1:27394': Connection refused

What is wrong? Does it seem like FTP creates a new port randomly when I run the `ls` command?

I want to forward my local FTP to my SSH/VPS, and run FTP from my SSH/VPS to my local machine normally, can someone help me and provide a solution? Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

FTP is a horrible protocol.  Yes, it uses multiple ports; there's the control port and then each data transfer (`ls` or `get` and so on) opens a second new random port.

Worse, depending on if you're doing PASV or active mode FTP, the *server* could try to initiate the connection.

FTP isn't easy to handle with forwarding like this.  Since you have ssh connectivity, can't you use `sftp`?  That's an FTP-like protocol that's built directly into ssh so no need to port forward.

Comment: actually I just want to separate the connection between FTP and SFTP (SSH), but if it turns out this is quite difficult to do, then I will just follow your advice and use SFTP. Thank You for taking your time to answer my question!

Comment: "FTP is a horrible protocol" – Related: [*FTP Must Die*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Comment: @TuanHaxor what is your goal behind "separate the connection"? (There might be a different way to achieve that.)

Comment: FTP has been designed around a use case that is uncommon today: server-to-server transfers. It is possible for a client to open two control connections and tell one server to send the file to the other. The downside of this is that it is difficult to get through a firewall, anyone who's ever deployed SIP based telephony infrastructure might recognize the issues.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann There is no specific goal bro

Answer (score -3):

FTP appears to be trying to use IP6, but you've only tunneled IP4. Try starting ftp with the -4 option.

Comment: You’re correct that’s an IPv6 address but it’s localhost, so not the problem. The issue is that FTP can’t open a connection for data because it’s not able to be tunneled in this way (Steven’s answer)